# Linking rows in the MySQL database and querying with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, row

I've just finished my first site with PHP and I'm just now noticing an issue. A lot of my dynamic content is "linked" to rows in other tables. So when those rows in the other tables are deleted, it obviously gives me an error.

For instance, I have a table "book_groups" that pulls data from the tables "books", "hosts" and "locations". So after I query a certain book_group, I make more queries to the other tables based on the book_id, host_id and location_id that are stored with the group.

I obviously hadn't planned well enough. Because if a book is accidentally deleted then re-added, the id will change and it will be broken.

My question is what is the best way to fix this now that I have it all practically finished? I could go back to every query and add an if( $query_result != false ) to see if the row still exists. But man there are a lot of queries because I have a lot of different types of groups and related tables.

For future reference, is there a better way to link tables in MySQL instead of just storing the id of the related table row?

Comment: You're linking them correctly. One solution is to have a provision in your code where if a book is deleted, book_groups relying on that book are deleted as well. Many MVC frameworks have out of the box solutions for this kind of functionality such as Rails dependent: :destroy (I know you're using PHP - that was just the first example that came to mind)

Comment: Seems to me a one to many mapping.  I guess it's too late to INNER JOIN your queries?  I think the "book_group" should only be a list of ids associated to a book and then make an INNER JOIN by group_id, you'll only fetch books that exist in the books table and you can prune your book_group later.

Comment: I don't want to delete any of the groups. I just want to be able to change which book is currently associated with it. I don't know anything about MVC frameworks (this is all new to me) but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subject is Referential Integrity. In MySQL you can enforce such integrity through database triggers.

For instance, you could define a trigger that executes before a `delete` happens on a parent record:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_books_bef_delete
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON books
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM book_groups WHERE book_id = old.book_id;
END;
```

This particular trigger will delete any dependent records in `book_groups` that refer to the `book` record being deleted.

You can decide to respond differently, and raise an error whenever a `book` record is being deleted that has dependent records. As from MySQL 5.5, you can do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_books_bef_delete
    BEFORE DELETE
    ON books
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM book_groups WHERE book_id = old.book_id) > 0
    THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Foreign Key Constraint Violated!';
    END IF;
END;
```

In this case, if a `book_groups` record is found that refers to the `book` record being deleted, a harsh exception is raised, and the `delete` operation is cancelled.

You can read about referential integrity with `MySql` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html).

You could do similar things in `PHP`, but that leaves the possibility to bypass such code when connected via other tools, like `phpAdmin`. The advantage of triggers is that they executed independent from where you connect from and that they execute in the same transaction as the principle operation. The disadvantage is that you have another layer of code to maintain, next to the `php` code. And that `php` code must be aware of the side-effects on other tables these triggers might have.

Some ideas for doing a controlled `delete` of a `book` in `php`:

```
$confirmed = false;
if (isset($_POST["confirm"])) {
    $confirmed = true;
}

$book_id = $_POST["book_id"]);

$con = mysqli_connect(...);

// Check for dependent records that would also be deleted:
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 
        "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM book_groups WHERE book_id = ?")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $book_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $cnt);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    if ($cnt > 0 && !$confirmed) {
        ?>
        <html>
        <body>  
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="<?=$book_id?>"/>
                This book is categorised in groups, 
                are you sure to delete that information?
                <input type="submit" value="confirm" name="confirm"/> 
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
        exit;
    }
}

// continue to delete book below...
```

Comment: It looks like that second solution might work. But I'd like all database queries to be possible through the CMS I created with PHP. Could I somehow make that query in PHP and tell the user which records are still relying on it before it's deleted, then prompt to continue anyway if desired?

Comment: Sure, you would do a `mysqli_query` to count the number of records in `books_query` that have the same id, then see if it is non-zero, present a page where user must submit their OK, and if you your `php` sees that confirmation parameter present, you perform the deletes.

Comment: I have added some indications for such `php` code. Not tested, just for giving an idea.

Comment: Looks like that's probably what I need. Now I just have to figure out what all those functions do... :P Thanks for your awesome help!